# Running Java builds with packages defined from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class, classpath

I am fairly new to Java and wrote simple a program to strip unwanted contents from a CSV export.

The top of the program looks like this:

```
package csv;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

    public class csvstrip {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
```

Eclipse automatically builds the csvstrip.class in a folder {workspace}\bin\csv. However, whatever I type into command line (running it using the java command), I get the following:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class csvstrip
```

If I remove the package declaration from the code, Eclipse asks if you wish to move the csvstrip class to the default package and builds the the class a level up in the folder {workspace}\bin. Now, on entering

```
java csvstrip
```

the program functions fine. Before removing the package csv declaration, I tried:

```
java csv.csvstrip
java csvstrip
```

from both the bin and bin\csv folder but nothing seemed to run. What piece of information am I missing here? If you define a package for your code, from where in command line are you supposed to run the java command and how should your program be referenced?

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you are trying to run the class file from top level or default package folder.
java will obviously throw you 'Class Not Found' error, because you are looking in the wrong directory.

trying running.

`java .\csv\csvstrip`

in the assumption that you are in the present working directory which contains csv folder within which you have csvstrip or try giving the complete path.

Comment: Okay. suppose your folder is in c:\topfolder\csv
then do the follwing on command line, assuming you are in C: drive.
C:\> cd topfolder\csv
and then 
java csvstrip

Comment: No no... You should stand in the "top folder" and do `java csv.csvstrip`.

Comment: Yeah. I agree. I tried again my way i was unable to get it. Your method works fine

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration you should be able to start your class standing in the bin folder and typing

```
java csv.csvstrip
```

...or...

```
java csv/csvstrip
```

should also work just fine

If you are on a windows machine please double check the case of your class file and of your package folder. Windows is case insensitive java classloader isn't.